# redirect 301 doesn't work for 3 URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 3 specific URLs that I need to redirect to 3 other specific URLS.

In htaccess I have:

```
redirect 301 /original-first-url/ /new-first-url/

redirect 301 /original-second-url/ /new-second-url/

redirect 301 /original-third-url/ /new-third-url/
```

This works find for the first url, but the second and third url also get redirected to /new-first-url/

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/original-first-url/ /new-first-url/ [R=301,L] 
    RewriteRule ^/original-second-url/ /new-second-url/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule  ^/original-third-url/ /new-third-url/ [R=301,L]

</IFModule>
```